# Log4net reference assembly dependency issue

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am a Java developer and have just started learning C# to develop a couple project. I am happy to see that many Java frameworks that I am used to work with (log4j, ant, hibernate etc.) have their .net versions (log4net, nant, nhibernate).

I have just created a project and tried to put log4net assembly reference in it, but I am having the following warning (followed by 4 errors informing failure to recognize log4net namespace and classes):

> The referenced assembly "log4net"
>   could not be resolved because it has a
>   dependency on "System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which
>   is not in the currently targeted
>   framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
>   Please remove references to assemblies
>   not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.

I added reference to `System.Web.ApplicationServices` and `System.Web.Services` but it's not working. Any help on solving this dependency issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

If you're still getting this error, you're using an out-of-date version of log4net and you should consider updating to the [current version](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi), which does not require the full .NET 4.0 framework.  Thanks to [@Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35274/philippe) for pointing this out in a comment.

---

Your project is referencing the .NET 4.0 *client profile* which does not include System.Web; you actually need to reference the *full* framework.

See [How To: Target a Specific .NET Framework Version or Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) on MSDN for directions.

> 1. In Visual Studio, open the project you want to change.
> 2. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and then click Properties.
> 3. In the Project Designer, locate the Target Framework list, as follows.
>
>    - For Visual Basic projects, click the Compile tab and then click
>        Advanced Compile Options. The Target
>        Framework list is in the Advanced
>        Compiler Settings dialog box.
>    - For Visual C# projects, the Target Framework list is on the
>        Application tab of the Project
>        Designer. For more information, see
>        Application Page, Project Designer
>        (C#).
>    - For Visual F# projects, the Target Framework list is on the
>        Application tab of the Project
>        Designer.
> 4. In the Target Framework list, select the .NET Framework version or
>      profile that you want. When you click
>      OK, the project unloads and then
>      reloads in the integrated development
>      environment (IDE). The project now
>      targets the .NET Framework version
>      that you just selected.

Possibly also of interest is [Troubleshooting .NET Framework Targeting Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668079.aspx).

Comment: This was very helpful.  The first project I created after installing Visual Studio 2010 set the target to the Client Profile by default

Comment: If targeting the client profile was valid, Maciej and 101100's answers are better: use the version of log4net that does not depend on system.web (1.2.11).

Answer (score 6):

Set your project to target the ".Net 4.0 Framework", not the ".Net 4.0 Framework Client Profile" in the project properties dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Just small update.
This issue has been logged almost 3 years ago and was fixed just this month. So next version of log4net (after 1.2.10) should be fine to work with client profile frameworks.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-174

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error with version 1.2.11 and you don't want to change your project's framework, simply install the version for the client profile.  This is in the `net-cp` folder in the binary distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference for future users:

Don't forget to also ***INSTALL*** the framework you target!
(I, myself, thought that because all the folders (v4.0x, v2.0X, etc.) were there I had all frameworks.  NOT!
It turns out I only had the .NET 4.0 **client profile** installed on my system and could not find the System.Web, even though the right framework was targeted.

Anyway, download your needed .net framework here:
[.NET Frameworks Microsoft Downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=.NET%20framework)